# Can I force IE10 to use accelerated GPU rendering?

Tags: rendering, hardware-acceleration, internet-explorer-10

In my copy of IE10, the option "Use software rendering instead of GPU rendering" (on the "Advanced" tab in the options) is checked by default and greyed oun so that it cannot be disabled using the UI.

Ok my graphics card is not a beast (Intel 945GME), but it does support OpenGL, so is there a hack that would allow me to test the IE10 with GPU rendering?

Comment: It's not just OpenGL support or similar. The card must support some specific instructions for this to work and I'm pretty sure that 945 doesn't support that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [945GME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_GMA#GMA_950)'s OpenGL support **is** software rendering. From the linked Wikipedia page:

> The GMA 950 shares the same architectural weakness as the GMA 900: no hardware geometry processing. Neither basic hardware transform and lighting, nor more advanced vertex shaders are handled in the GMA hardware, these are only accessible via Software Rendering.